# pip install nltk command throws import error in Cloudera

Tags: python, cloudera-cdh

I am getting

```
**ImportError: No module named pip**
```

when executed

```
pip install nltk command
```

I am a Beginner in python. Can anyone please suggest me a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must install "easy-install" package using ,

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python
```

then install "pip" ,

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Then you are good to go

```
pip install nltk
```